# simple html dom parser getting values

Tags: php

I am using simple_html_dom.php

How to get following data

```
<td class="t-loss">% Change<strong>-10.75</strong></td>
```

I want to get -10.75
t-loss occurs only once in html code

```
<p class="data" id="bseVolume">22,621</p>
```

I want to get 22,621 
bsevolume occurs only once in html code

please let me know what code should I use.

*edit* more info:

```
$bseVolume = $content->find("//p[contains(@class, 'data')]");
```

`class : data` appears multiple times in html but `id="bseVolume"` appears only once.
I tried

```
$vaue1 = $html->find("//p[contains(@id, 'bseVolume')]"); 
$volume1 = $bseVolume1[0]->innertext; echo $volume1 ;
```

The result is blank. Can you comment?

Comment: $bseVolume = $content->find("//p[contains(@class, 'data')]");  class : data appears multiple times in html but id="bseVolume" appears  only once. I tried $vaue1 = $html->find("//p[contains(@id, 'bseVolume')]"); $volume1 = $bseVolume1[0]->innertext; echo  $volume1 ; The result i blank. Can you comment

Comment: I edited your post with the additional information you added above.  In the future, please `edit` your post when adding pertinent information.  It's fine to answer questions in the comments, or add info that is not "required" for users to be able to answer your question.  My edit will appear after it has been peer reviewed and passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple HTML DOM [find](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) to find the `<td>` or `<p>` elements.

From the docs:

> Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero
>   based)
>
> $ret = $html->find('a', 0);

You could find the `<p>` you are looking for like this:

```
$bseVolume = $html->find("p[id=bseVolume]", 0);
echo $bseVolume->innertext();
```

You could find the `<td>` you are looking for like this:

```
$tLoss = $html->find("td[class=t-loss] strong", 0);
echo $tLoss->innertext();
```